# evaluate.rdb not find . R markdown not working properly

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I am getting an error while working with rmarkdown. Even a very basic code is throwing an error. I also tried to reinstallation of both R and R studio but that doesn't seems to be work. Please help me on this. Tried every possible step

[snapshot of my code][1]

````
```{r}

3*2

```
````

processing file: trial.Rmd
  |................                                                 |  25%
label: unnamed-chunk-1

Quitting from lines 2-3 (trial.Rmd) 
Error in get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) : 
  cannot open file 'C:/Users/ravin/Documents/R/win-library/3.2/evaluate/R/evaluate.rdb': No such file or directory
Calls:  ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> 
Execution halted

```
sessionInfo()



R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) 
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) 
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200) 

locale: 
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252 LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252 
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C 
[5] LC_TIME=English_India.1252 

attached base packages: 
[1] stats graphics grDevices utils datasets methods base 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached)
```

Comment: Did it work before? I could not replicate your problem. Can you update your question with the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: > sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.2 (2015-08-14)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_India.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_India.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_India.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=English_India.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):

Comment: Update your question, don't put it in the comments.

Comment: ok. kind of new to overflow

Comment: That's why I told you :P Can you update with the _entire_ output of `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: does `update.packages("evaluate")` work? If not, try `remove.packages("evaluate"); install.packages("evaluate")`

Comment: @PavoDive many thanks to you . how this didnt come to my mind .

Comment: @learner if it worked, you may consider checking the tick mark in your favorite answer.

Comment: @PavoDive i did that but due to low reputation my points are not worthy of consideration

Comment: @learner you haven't accepted yet the answer. Just below the voting of the answer there is a check mark. It'll become green as you click it, indicating it's accepted. That will *award you* some reputation points.

Comment: @PavoDive thanks kind of new to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your problem comes from a missing (or corrupted) file in the `evaluate` package.

To solve it, you could try this first:

```
update.packages("evaluate")
```

If it doesn't work, try uninstalling and re-installing the package:

```
remove.packages("evaluate")
install.packages("evaluate")
```